# Can we integrate Microsoft MapPoint services for iOS map navigation application?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, navigation, gps, mappoint

I have read up about Microsoft MapPoint 2011 here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc983790.aspx.

It provides Map Navigation support using GPS system. Can we integrate this functionality in my iOS application?

I want to develop an application where user gets source to destination direction using GPS service.

Please guide me about MapPoint and feel free to suggest if there are any other options available.

Thanks in advance.

Mrunal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapPoint is a desktop program for Windows PCs. So the answer is No.

you might be getting confused with MapPoint Web Services which are being discontinued in the next few months. An alternative network solution would be Bing Maps which includes both AJAX controls and web services.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you provide any link to develop iphone navigation application using Bing Maps?

Comment: Try the Microsoft Bing Maps site and forums (sorry on the road and on an iPad, so I don't have the links handy)

Comment: Thanks winwaed.. Its really useful.. I have studied over bing maps too.. There is iOS sdk is also available to support Bing Map. Is there any tutorial or sample applicaition available for that..